# How does fill-paragraph (M-q) in emacs work inside LaTeX equations?

Tags: emacs, latex

I have not really understood how this works (and maybe it works differently in Aquamacs and GNU emacs on linux) - sometimes it does not fold long lines inside equations. I would like to know if there is a nice way to fold equations with M-q.

Comment: Can you give a particular example?

Comment: I have problems folding long lines with previews enabled. Is that what you meant here? If so then it's a valid question and I hope someone can address it. Most likely it's an issue of auctex.